# why the sizeof the image i load is different from the size measured by ImageJ, almost about 0.88 times?

Tags: java, android, imageview, size

```
ImageView imgBkg;
imgBkg=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgBkg);
int width =imgBkg.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth();
int height=imgBkg.getDrawable().getIntrinsicHeight();
```

i  have load a picture, the id is `imgBkg`, but when i use `getIntrinsicWidth` get the width of the image, it is different from the size i get from `ImageJ`

What is the reason of this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

The API reference tells you. the **Intrinsic** width is the exact size of the image as its is saved in your resources, regardless of re-size in your ImageView.